# Selection not updating data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to update a data array with D3.js but it's doesn't work.

I've read documentation of D3, and many demos on bl.ocks.org but my issue still persist. I don't understand why. I miss something, but I don't find what is this.

This is my code:

```
const data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42]
const data2 = [3, 6, 9, 17, 45]

const button = `<button>Click</button>`
document.querySelector('body').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', button)

const svg = d3.select('body')
.append('svg')

const renderArray = (data) => {
    const group = svg.selectAll('g')
    .data(d => data)

    group.exit().remove()

    group.enter()
        .append('g')
        .merge(group)
        .attr('id', d => d)

    const p = group.selectAll("text")
    .data(d => d)

    p.enter()
        .append("text")
        .merge(p)
        .text((d) => d)

    p.exit().remove()
}

renderArray(data)

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => renderArray(data2))
```

My pen : https://codepen.io/Tirkal/pen/OKOvzN?editors=0010

I expect the update of data array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two main problems:

First, selections are *immutable*. Therefore, the `merge` function here...

```
group.enter()
    .append('g')
    .merge(group)
    //etc...
```

... is not going to change `group`. You have to reassign it:

```
group = group.enter()
    //etc...
```

Second, the `data` function only accepts three things: an array, a function or nothing. That being said, for the texts, it should be:

```
const p = group.selectAll("text")
    .data(d => [d])
    //array-----^
```

Even better, since those values are not inner arrays or objects just drop those `text` selections and append the texts directly.

There are other minor problems, but those two are the most important ones.

Here is the resulting code:

```js
const data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42]
const data2 = [3, 6, 9, 17, 45]

const button = `<button>Click</button>`
document.querySelector('body').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', button)

const svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')

const renderArray = (data) => {
  let group = svg.selectAll('g')
    .data(data)

  group.exit().remove()

  group = group.enter()
    .append('g')
    .merge(group)
    .attr("transform", (_, i) => "translate(10," + (i * 20) + ")")
    .attr('id', d => d)

  const p = group.selectAll("text")
    .data(d => [d])

  p.enter()
    .append("text")
    .merge(p)
    .text((d) => d)

  p.exit().remove()
}

renderArray(data)

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => renderArray(data2))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```